# bind ondblclick event to each item in a list and pass that item's value in the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This seems to be straight-forward but probably i am missing something. I try to bind each item's ondblclick event in the list and pass it's value to an editor so when the item is clicked, its text concats in the editor. For some reason only first item keeps appending to the editor text even when i click on second or third items..

```
$('#listComments').each(function (index, item) {
  $('#listComments')[0][i].ondblclick = function () {
                    alert(i);
                    var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");
                    editor.exec("inserthtml", { value: commentSet[i] });
                };
```

commentsSet is another temp array that is filled with the original values as follows

```
 var commentsSet = [];

 $.ajax({
        url: urlComments,
        data: { headerId: $('#ddlCommentHeaders').val().toString() },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            $('#listComments').empty();
            commentSet = [];

            $.each(result, function (index, value) {
                commentSet[index] = value.comment;
                $('#listComments').append($('<option>').text($(value.comment).text()).val(value.CommentID));
           });



            for (var i = 0; i < $('#listComments')[0].length; i++) {
                $('#listComments')[0][i].ondblclick = function () {
                    alert(i);
                    var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");
                    editor.exec("inserthtml", { value: commentSet[i] });
                };
            }

        }
    });
```

Basically the value.comment has a text with html tags which i would need in the editor but to display in the list item i only need plain text without html tags, so i have filled a temp array with html text and bound the list with plain text values.
The ondblclick event is only present in the first item of list.
I hope i am able to explain my issue. :)

**UPDATE**

In browser when i type $('#listComments')

> [select#listComments.classComments, context: document, selector:
>   "#listComments"] 0 : select#listComments.classComments context :
>   document length : 1 selector : "#listComments"
>   **proto** : Object(0)

$('#listComments').length is 1

$('#listComments')[0]

```
<select class="classComments" id="listComments" multiple="multiple" name="cM.CommentsList" style="height:105px; margin-bottom:5px; max-width:100%;"><option value="1382" style="white-space: pre-wrap;">This is a Math Comment</option><option value="1383">This is a second Comment</option></select>
```

$('#listComments')[0].length is 2

**HTML**

```
<div style="margin-left:5px;  width:80%" class=" col-xs-9">
                        @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.cM.CommentsList, new SelectList(Model.cM.CommentsList, "CommentID", "Comment"), new { @id = "listComments", @style = "height:105px; margin-bottom:5px; max-width:100%;", @class="classComments" })
                    </div>
```

**Jquery** each function

```
$('#listComments').each(function (index, item) {
                item.ondblclick = function () {
                    alert(index);
                    editor.exec("inserthtml", { value: commentSet[index] });
                };
            });
```

**Answer**

Although both Muhammad-Yousuf also has given a correct solution i could only mark one of the answers correct. I also referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152845/double-click-event-on-option-of-listbox-not-firing-in-ie) post. did it this way..and thanks to Luke for constant support.

```
 $('#listComments').dblclick(function (){
                $("#listComments option:selected").each(function () { 
                    var index = $(this).index();
                    var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");
                    editor.exec("inserthtml", { value: commentSet[index] });
                });
            });
```

Comment: first look .. Id must be unique use class instead *don't use same id for more than one element*

Comment: replaced all #listComments with .classComments... same behaviour

Comment: Edit your html with rendered html .. and I prefer to not mixing jquery with pure js

Comment: i am using jquery only since it did not work i tried with js too but even that is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just read your code correctly and noticed you're trying to wire a double click event to an option within a select, I dont believe this will work how you are expecting it to. Try looping over the selects options and setting each value to the the correct index, then wire an onchange event to the commentList, in that event get the current value (index) and use that to get the correct item from your array.

Something like

```
$('#listComments option').each(item, index) {
    $(item).data('index', index);
}

$('#listComments')[0].dblclick = function() {
    var index = $('#listComments option:selected').data('index');
    alert(index);
    var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");
    editor.exec("inserthtml", { value: commentSet[index] });
}
```

Comment: but i dont need anything on single click but on double click

Answer (score 1):

Try this code and if it works I'll explain it

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlComments,
    data: { headerId: $('#ddlCommentHeaders').val().toString() },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        $('#listComments').empty();
        $.each(result, function (index, value) {
            //commentSet[index] = value.comment;
            $('#listComments').append($('<option>')
            .text($(value.comment).text())
            .val(value.CommentID)
            .data('comment' , value.comment)
       });
    }
});

$(document).on('dblclick' , '#listComments option', function () {
    var getComment_Value = $(this).data('comment');
    var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");
    editor.exec("inserthtml", { value: getComment_Value });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
for (var i = 0; i < $('#listComments').length; i++) {
    $('#listComments').eq(i).ondblclick = function () {
        alert(i);
        var editor = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor");
        editor.exec("inserthtml", { value: commentSet[i] });
    };
}
```

Not sure why you are doing

```
$('#listComments')[0].length
```

If you html looks like

```
<ul id="listComments">
    <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Then you will need

```
$('#listComments > li').length
$('#listComments > li').eq(i)
```

Comment: $('#listComments').length returns length 1 only..you can see my markup in the update

Comment: Could you please include the rendered markup instead

Comment: its there now <select><option>...</option></select>

Comment: Great, so try $('#listComments option').length and then inside your loop try $('#listComments option').eq(i) or if you use a jquery.each simply $('#listComments option').each and then $(item) inside your each function.

Comment: there is no crash/error in browser but the loop doesnot move to the second item..i have added my jquery code in the update.

Comment: so when i dblclick the second item in list...alert(index) gives 0 only and there is no 1

Comment: Your example shows $('#listComments').each try $('#listComments option').each